# Water particle model

Tags: c++, c, particles

I want to design a physical particle system in order to model/simulate a flowing water on a terrain. I want to use C (maybe C++) in order to do that. Do you guys know any good examples or a good starting point to do this?Thank you!

Comment: Simulating flowing water is actually a huge undertaking; it's something that people actively do research in. Do you know what you're getting yourself into? Do you want to be able to visualize your results? How realistic do you want it? Are "video-game" approximations okay, or do you want it to be as close to physical reality as possible?

Comment: Do you want to display your simulation in 3d graphic? Have you tried anything? Do you need algorithms or are you implementing yours own?

Comment: Try this: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/rope_physics/17006/

Comment: Modelling individual particles would take you a computer whose size would be measured on a galactic scale....

Comment: Yes i know it's a huge undertaking. I am currently working on this project where I have a cluster and develop some distributed and parallel computing for particle models.At first I would just like to run the program with a water flow case-study model. Only in the end will I be preoccupied with the display.I am trying to implement my own. Thank you for the links. I will take a look over them. Of course any other suggestions/critics and other stuff are always ok

Answer (score 1):

maybe can be useful [Fluid simulation library](http://codeanticode.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/fluid-library-for-processing/)